# Highcharts: how to draw annotations on drag and release action, instated of click and release?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/pk8s3cnf/3/) from where we can draw different annotations.

The annotations are drawn on mouse-click event: so user has to click first and then to release the mouse (in order drawing to start) and then to click the mouse again (in order to complete).
What I want to accomplish is drawing to start without user to have to release the mouse: so user has to click the mouse and drawing to start immediately, then user is dragging the mouse around the chart to the point where he want to complete and then to release the mouse in order drawing to complete.

Basically, I need to be able to draw annotations with "**click-drag-release**" and at the moment I can do that only with "**click-release-drag-click-release**"

I am using [highcharts stock-tools](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/stock-tools) as annotations, in a way that they are defined as

```
<div class="annotation-container" style="margin-left:60px">
  <button class="highcharts-circle-annotation button">Add Circle</button>
  <button class="highcharts-arrow-segment button">Add Arrow</button>  
  <button class="highcharts-segment button">Add Line</button>
</div>
```

and then they are binded into the navigation as

```
navigation: {
  annotationsOptions: {
    shapeOptions: {
      fill: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
      stroke: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
      strokeWidth: 2,
      borderColor: 'gray',
      type: 'rect',
      borderWidth: 2
    }
  },
  bindingsClassName: 'annotation-container',
    events: {
      selectButton: function(event) {
        // Select button
        event.button.classList.add('active');
        // Register this is current button to indicate we're adding an annotation.
        this.chart.activeButton = event.button;
      },
      deselectButton: function(event) {
        // Unselect the button
        event.button.classList.remove('active');
        // Remove info about active button:
        this.chart.activeButton = null;
      }
   }
},
```

Comment: Hi @delux, That is not supported in Highcharts by default. You need to manually change `click` event to `mousedown` in the `initEvents` method, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wyj2x4ep/

Comment: @ppotaczek I was trying to extend your solution further, but was not able to figure it out, due the more advanced features incuded here. True that now drawing starts on `mousedown`, but it should also end on `mouseup` (which is not the case). And also, while drawing is active, the chart should not scroll (at the moment it acts as the user is dragging the chart).

Comment: Hi @delux, Sorry for the late replay! I am leaving a link to your second question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65667708/highcharts-how-to-draw-line-segments-with-click-and-drag-and-without-chart-to-s