# Highcharts: how to draw line segments with click-and-drag and without chart to scroll?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having my code inside of [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/vqydcLf6/) and as a reference I am considering [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/jh8pcxd9/1/).
When I am trying to draw a `segment` annotation or an `arrow-segment` annotation, the whole chart is scrolling. Additionally, drawing can not be performed in a single mouse click and dragging to draw.

Here [is an example video](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/crVXIXPgHr) of how I want my chart to works v.s. how it actually works. The implementation for this behavior was initiated in the method `customInitEvents`, but I am not sure how to proceed further from there.

```
(function(H) {
  function customInitEvents() {
    var objectEach = H.objectEach,
      addEvent = H.addEvent,
      isFunction = H.isFunction;

    var navigation = this,
      chart = navigation.chart,
      bindingsContainer = navigation.container,
      options = navigation.options;

    this.removeEvents();
    // Shorthand object for getting events for buttons:
    navigation.boundClassNames = {};
    objectEach((options.bindings || {}), function(value) {
      navigation.boundClassNames[value.className] = value;
    });
    // Handle multiple containers with the same class names:
    [].forEach.call(bindingsContainer, function(subContainer) {
      navigation.eventsToUnbind.push(addEvent(subContainer, 'click', function(event) {
        var bindings = navigation.getButtonEvents(subContainer,
          event);
        if (bindings) {
          navigation.bindingsButtonClick(bindings.button, bindings.events, event);
        }
      }));
    });
    objectEach(options.events || {}, function(callback, eventName) {
      if (isFunction(callback)) {
        navigation.eventsToUnbind.push(addEvent(navigation, eventName, callback));
      }
    });
    navigation.eventsToUnbind.push(addEvent(chart.container, 'mousedown', function(e) {
      if (!chart.cancelClick &&
        chart.isInsidePlot(e.chartX - chart.plotLeft, e.chartY - chart.plotTop)) {
        navigation.bindingsChartClick(this, e);
      }
    }));
    navigation.eventsToUnbind.push(addEvent(chart.container, 'mouseup', function(e) {
      if (!chart.cancelClick &&
        chart.isInsidePlot(e.chartX - chart.plotLeft, e.chartY - chart.plotTop)) {
        navigation.bindingsChartClick(this, e);
      }
    }));
    navigation.eventsToUnbind.push(addEvent(chart.container, H.isTouchDevice ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove', function(e) {
      navigation.bindingsContainerMouseMove(this, e);
    }));
  }

  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'initNavigationBindings', function(proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    customInitEvents.call(this.navigationBindings);
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality requires custom code. After wrapping the `initNavigationBindings` method, you can refactor the `initEvents` method and include `mousedown` and `mouseup` events:

```
(function(H) {
    function customInitEvents() {
        ...
        navigation.eventsToUnbind.push(addEvent(chart.container, 'mousedown', function(e) {
            if (!chart.cancelClick &&
                    chart.isInsidePlot(e.chartX - chart.plotLeft, e.chartY - chart.plotTop)) {
                e.isFakeClickEvent = true;
                navigation.bindingsChartClick(chart, e);
            }
        }));

        navigation.eventsToUnbind.push(addEvent(chart.container, 'mouseup', function(e) {
            chart.pointer.normalize(e);
            navigation.bindingsChartClick(chart, e);
        }));
        ...
    }

    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'initNavigationBindings', function(proceed) {
        var chart = this;

        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        chart.navigationBindings.removeEvents();

        customInitEvents.call(chart.navigationBindings);
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eb7qsf63/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: this solution handled the part with the clicks, but panning still does not work as I need to. Panning should be enabled and should not be applied only while user is drawing the annotations. Here in this code https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/fojd7zuv/2/ I enabled the panning and you can see how I tried to manipulate with it on `mousedown` and `mouseup` events. But, the options which I tried are not working for me. Can you please assist me, how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Hi @delux, You were close., please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f7eac92d/ You can add some custom flag on a chart and wrap the `pan` method.

Comment: thank you! I wonder, the methods which you used in this solution, like `navigation.eventsToUnbind` and `navigation.bindingsChartClick` can these be found somewhere in the official docs for the highcharts? I am wondering, since even when you provided me the initial solution, I was not able to find these methods anywhere in the docs.

Comment: The methods are internal and I found them in the source code, for example: https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations-advanced.src.js

Comment: here is one issue I found: https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/n21kofx9/3/. If I add `stock-tools` menu on the left and when drawing line, if I release the mouse while I am on the actual `stock-tools` menu, afterwards drawing goes wrong (example: https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/crV2QfPPqI). It works well if I release outside of the chart area, but in case I release while I am over `stock-tools`, then it goes wrong. I assume normalization on `mouse up` event is causing the issue?

Comment: That is because the `mouseup` event is added only on the chart container. Please test this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bsnjxmw6/ with the `mouseup` event added on document.